# How to split into train_loader and test_loader using PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torch, pytorch-dataloader

I have a project which uses PyTorch and I have no knowledge of it.

I have a CSV with 7 columns, the last is the label while the first 6 are features.

My project says to split the data randomly into train_loader and test_loader. I have made the labels but I am certain that they are incorrect.

My code looks like this:

```
import torch
import torch.utils.data as data
import torch.utils.data.dataset as dataset
import numpy as np
import pickle
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler


class Nav_Dataset(dataset.Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = np.genfromtxt('saved/training_data.csv', delimiter=',')
        self.x = self.data[:, 0:5]
        self.y = self.data[:, [6]]
# it may be helpful for the final part to balance the distribution of your collected data

        # normalize data and save scaler for inference
        self.scaler = MinMaxScaler()
        self.normalized_data = self.scaler.fit_transform(self.data) #fits and transforms
        pickle.dump(self.scaler, open("saved/scaler.pkl", "wb")) #save to normalize at inference

    def __len__(self):
# __len__() returns the length of the dataset
        return len(self.y)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if not isinstance(idx, int):
            idx = idx.item()
# for this example, __getitem__() must return a dict with entries {'input': x, 'label': y}
# x and y should both be of type float32. There are many other ways to do this, but to work with autograding
# please do not deviate from these specifications.
        y = self.y[idx]
        x = self.x[idx]
        sample = {'input': x, 'label': y}
        return sample


class Data_Loaders():
    def __init__(self, batch_size):
        self.nav_dataset = Nav_Dataset()
# randomly split dataset into two data.DataLoaders, self.train_loader and self.test_loader
# make sure your split can handle an arbitrary number of samples in the dataset as this may vary


def main():
    batch_size = 16
    data_loaders = Data_Loaders(batch_size)
    # note this is how the dataloaders will be iterated over, and cannot be deviated from
    for idx, sample in enumerate(data_loaders.train_loader):
        _, _ = sample['input'], sample['label']
    for idx, sample in enumerate(data_loaders.test_loader):
        _, _ = sample['input'], sample['label']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I cannot understand how to make the train and test dataloaders and split the dataset. Any help to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch provides a convenient utility function just for this, called [`random_split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.random_split).

```
from torch.utils.data import random_split, DataLoader

class Data_Loaders():
    def __init__(self, batch_size, split_prop=0.8):
        self.nav_dataset = Nav_Dataset()
        
        # compute number of samples
        self.N_train = int(len(self.nav_dataset) * 0.8)
        self.N_test = len(self.nav_dataset) - self.N_train

        self.train_set, self.test_set = random_split(self.nav_dataset, \
                                      [self.N_train, self.N_test])
        
        self.train_loader = DataLoader(self.train_set, batch_size=batch_size, ..)
        self.test_loader = DataLoader(self.test_set, batch_size=batch_size, ..)
```

First compute the number of samples for both subsets and then use `random_split` to split them. Lastly, create the data loaders out of the datasets.